# How to create a Calculation based on multiple criteria in IBM Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-11, websphere

I am trying to create a calculation in Cognos based on a number of Criteria. 
For example, I want to get a count of all of the records in my data set that have the following criteria:

Data_Level = "Aggregate"
Problem_Area = "Request"
IsResearch = "No"
Substate_ID = "Incomplete - Cancelled"

I want to then call this value: 'Aggregated Data - Non Research'

Thanks in advance for your feedback. I'm conducting a feasibility test of Cognos compared to other BI Tools so I am trying to replicate the same report across tools to gauge their usability. So far I am finding Cognos the most difficult to find resources on.

Regards,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create an if then else field which gives you a 1 if the conditions are met and 0 if they are not,  then total that.

total(If ([Data_Level] = "Aggregate" and [Problem_Area] = "Request" and [IsResearch] = "No"
and [Substate_ID] = "Incomplete - Cancelled")
then (1)
else (0))

Comment: That exactly the type of thing I am trying to do but it doesn't like the Syntax. I really want to like Cognos but it seem so difficult to use compared to other tools.

Comment: Telling us the expression that you are trying and the error could help.

Breaking the problem into smaller chunks could also help you identify where the problem actually is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function **total** and **define the scope**

For example, 
Create a data item "Aggregated Data - Non Research"

Expression:

```
    If ([Data_Level] = "Aggregate" and [Problem_Area] = "Request" 
and [IsResearch] = "No" and [
Substate_ID] = "Incomplete - Cancelled") 
then (1) else (0)
```

Then you can add another data item, using the total function, with an expression that defines the scope:

```
Total([Aggregated Data - Non Research] for Company, Year, Month)
```